# Correct way to rotate object after instancing it in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a top down shooting game and I want the bullets to align with the direction they are shot at.
I'm passing the direction when instancing the bullet(code bellow) and applying it on the Start event but it doesn't rotate. However it applies when i use it on the Update event indicating that the value is indeed passed but somehow the Start event isn't able to rotate the object. I also tried the OnEnable event and same thing, it seems inneficient to set the rotation in every Update event how can i fix it.

```
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;
    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    private float distanceTravelled = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.LookAt(direction);;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += speed * Time.deltaTime * direction;
        distanceTravelled += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distanceTravelled > range)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be transform.LookAt(**target**)

Comment: If you want to rotate the transform along a direction, use `transform.forward = direction`

Comment: I'm pretty sure lookat(target) is the same as transform.forward = direction as it says on the documentation: "Rotates the transform so the forward vector points at /target/'s current position".
And it actually works if i call the code inside Update instead of Start.

Answer (score 1):

I think i fixed it, if theres a better solution please tell me :)
I used Invoke fujnction, it seems to delay the rotation enough so it gets properly applied.

```
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;
    public Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
    private float distanceTravelled = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(SetForwardVector), 0f);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position += speed * Time.deltaTime * direction;
        distanceTravelled += speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (distanceTravelled > range)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    void SetForwardVector()
    {
        transform.LookAt(direction);
    }
}
```